# How to secure client certificate info in python source code

Tags: python, security, certificate

We have a service that requires a client certificate to be presented with the request or the call will be rejected.  For our .NET components, we have the certificate installed in the local Windows cert store.  At runtime we can get the certificate by thumbprint and include that with our request.

For our python component, I am able to get the certificate from the store, but only the public data.  I can't seem to access the private key.  To get around this I have a pem file with the certificate data that python uses.  We are cleaning all secrets out of our source repository, so I need to remove this file.

Does anyone have a suggesiton on how I can access the private key for the certificate without checking it in with my code?  Things I am exploring are:

- Get the private key with the certificate from the windows cert store
- Continue to use the pem file, but encrypt it somehow
- Something else?

Thanks,
~john

Comment: Usually you would create the private key and a CSR on the client and get the the CSR signed by a CA to get a unique certificate. You don't distribute private certificates.